# How to make a game restart when player hits bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm making a simple side scrolling game using HTML and JavaScript, where a player jumps from platform to platform.

My question is, what command would I use to make the player "die" or go to "game over" screen when the player misses a platform and hits the bottom of the screen? Here is a link to the game in case you don't understand me:

https://output.jsbin.com/mevari

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #3399FF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
        canvas.width = 1024, canvas.height = 640;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var menu = true;

        var background = {
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            x: 472,
            //x: -8000
        };

        var player = {
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            x: canvas.width / 2 - 15,
            y: 10,
            velx: 0,
            vely: 0,
            speed: 4,
            friction: 0.8,
            gravity: 0.3,
            jumping: false
        };

        var player_stats = {
            lvl: 1
        };

        var starting_pos = {
            x: player.x,
            y: player.y
        };

        var keys = [];
        window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        }, false);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
            keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        }, false);

        function platform(x, y) {
            var platform = {
                x: x,
                y: y,
                width: 100,
                height: 30
            };
            background.width = platform.x + platform.width;
            context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
            context.fillRect(platform.x, platform.y, platform.width, platform.height);
            if (player.y + player.height > platform.y && player.y + player.height < platform.y + platform.height && player.x + player.width > platform.x && player.x < platform.x + platform.width) {
                player.jumping = false;
                player.vely = 0;
                player.y = platform.y - player.height;
            }
            if (player.x + player.width > platform.x && player.x + player.width < platform.x + platform.width / 2 && player.y + player.height > platform.y && player.y < platform.y + platform.height) {
                player.x = platform.x - player.width;
                player.jumping = true;
            }
            if (player.x < platform.x + platform.width && player.x > platform.x + platform.width / 2 && player.y + player.height > platform.y && player.y < platform.y + platform.height) {
                player.x = platform.x + platform.width;
                player.jumping = true;
            }
        }

        function update() {
            if (menu) {
                context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                context.fillStyle = "#3399FF";
                context.textAlign = "center";
                context.font = "120px Arial";
                context.fillText("Lord Hero", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 4);

                context.font = "30px Arial";
                context.fillText("Press Enter to play", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 1.5);
                if (keys[13] && menu) {
                    menu = !menu;
                }
            } else if (!menu) {

                if (keys[38] && !menu) {
                    if (!player.jumping) {
                        player.jumping = true;
                        player.vely = -player.speed * 2;
                    }
                }
                if (keys[39] && !menu) {
                    if (player.velx < player.speed) {
                        player.velx--;
                    }
                }
                if (keys[37] && !menu) {
                    if (player.velx > -player.speed) {
                        player.velx++;
                    }
                }

                if (player.y > canvas.height) {
                    player.x = starting_pos.x;
                    player.y = starting_pos.y;
                    player.velx = 0;
                    player.vely = 0;
                }

                player.velx *= player.friction;
                player.vely += player.gravity;

                background.x += player.velx;
                player.y += player.vely;

                context.fillStyle = "#3399FF";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
                context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
                // Platform width: 100 height: 30
                platform(background.x + 25, 100);
                platform(background.x + 125, 100);
                platform(background.x + 225, 130);
                platform(background.x + 425, 240);
                platform(background.x + 630, 180);
                platform(background.x + 850, 125);
                platform(background.x + 1050, 360);
                platform(background.x + 1250, 265);
                platform(background.x + 1490, 205);
                platform(background.x + 1770, 130);
                platform(background.x + 2050, 240);
                platform(background.x + 2420, 340);
                platform(background.x + 2790, 450);
                platform(background.x + 3050, 360);
                platform(background.x + 3300, 265);
                platform(background.x + 3555, 190);
                platform(background.x + 3810, 100);
                platform(background.x + 4170, 250);
                platform(background.x + 4570, 430);
                platform(background.x + 4810, 330);
                platform(background.x + 5150, 330);
                platform(background.x + 5490, 330);
                platform(background.x + 5750, 240);
                platform(background.x + 6010, 145);
                platform(background.x + 6480, 550);
                platform(background.x + 6940, 330);
                platform(background.x + 7200, 230);
                platform(background.x + 7450, 130);
                platform(background.x + 7810, 130);
                platform(background.x + 8220, 330);
                platform(background.x + 8650, 595);
                platform(background.x + 8890, 485);
                platform(background.x + 9240, 485);
                platform(background.x + 9570, 485);
                platform(background.x + 9850, 390);
                platform(background.x + 10120, 290);
                platform(background.x + 10350, 180);
                platform(background.x + 10790, 450);
                platform(background.x + 11050, 360);
                platform(background.x + 11300, 265);
                platform(background.x + 11555, 190);
                platform(background.x + 11810, 100);
                platform(background.x + 12170, 250);
                platform(background.x + 12570, 430);
                platform(background.x + 12810, 330);
                platform(background.x + 13150, 330);
                platform(background.x + 13490, 330);
                platform(background.x + 13750, 240);
                platform(background.x + 14010, 145);
                platform(background.x + 14480, 550);
                platform(background.x + 14700, 440);
                platform(background.x + 14940, 330);
                platform(background.x + 15200, 230);
                platform(background.x + 15450, 130);
                platform(background.x + 15810, 130);
                platform(background.x + 16220, 330);
                platform(background.x + 16650, 595);
                platform(background.x + 16890, 485);
                platform(background.x + 17240, 485);
                platform(background.x + 17570, 485);
                platform(background.x + 17850, 390);
                platform(background.x + 18120, 290);
                platform(background.x + 18350, 180);
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is [`cancelAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame)

What have I done?

1. `var ra = 0;` set a variable to store the `requestAnimationFrame()` id.
2. Change from `requestAnimationFrame(update);` to `ra = requestAnimationFrame(update);` to store the id.
3. After the program detect that the player hit the bottom (which was already check), you need to stop the animation, alert a message (or show some page) and prevent the code from continue using this:

   ```
   alert('game over');
   cancelAnimationFrame(ra);
   return;
   ```

The full code:

```js
var ra = 0;
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = 1024, canvas.height = 640;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var menu = true;

var background = {
  width: 0,
  height: 0,
  x: 472,
  //x: -8000
};

var player = {
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  x: canvas.width/2-15,
  y: 10,
  velx: 0,
  vely: 0,
  speed: 4,
  friction: 0.8,
  gravity: 0.3,
  jumping: false
};

var player_stats = {
  lvl: 1
};

var starting_pos = {
  x: player.x,
  y: player.y
};

var keys = [];
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}, false);

function platform(x, y) {
  var platform = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    width: 100,
    height: 30
  };
  background.width = platform.x + platform.width;
  context.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
  context.fillRect(platform.x, platform.y, platform.width, platform.height);
  if (player.y + player.height > platform.y && player.y + player.height < platform.y + platform.height && player.x + player.width > platform.x && player.x < platform.x + platform.width) {
    player.jumping = false;
    player.vely = 0;
    player.y = platform.y-player.height;
  }
  if (player.x + player.width > platform.x && player.x + player.width < platform.x + platform.width/2 && player.y + player.height > platform.y && player.y < platform.y + platform.height) {
    player.x = platform.x-player.width;
    player.jumping = true;
  }
  if (player.x < platform.x + platform.width && player.x > platform.x + platform.width/2 && player.y + player.height > platform.y && player.y < platform.y + platform.height) {
    player.x = platform.x+platform.width;
    player.jumping = true;
  }
}

function update() {
  if (menu) {
    context.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.fillStyle="#3399FF";
    context.textAlign="center";
    context.font = "120px Arial";
    context.fillText("Lord Hero", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/4);

    context.font = "30px Arial";
    context.fillText("Press Enter to play", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/1.5);
    if (keys[13] && menu) {
      menu = !menu;
    }
  } else if (!menu) {

    if (keys[38] && !menu) {
      if(!player.jumping){
        player.jumping = true;
        player.vely = -player.speed*2;
      }
    }
    if (keys[39] && !menu) {
      if (player.velx < player.speed) {                         
        player.velx--;                  
      }          
    }          
    if (keys[37] && !menu) {                    
      if (player.velx > -player.speed) {
        player.velx++;
      }
    }

    if (player.y > canvas.height) {
      console.log('game over');
      alert('game over');
      cancelAnimationFrame(ra);
      return;
      //player.x = starting_pos.x;
      //player.y = starting_pos.y;
      //player.velx = 0;
      //player.vely = 0;
    }

    player.velx *= player.friction;
    player.vely += player.gravity;

    background.x += player.velx;
    player.y += player.vely;

    context.fillStyle="#3399FF";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
    context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    // Platform width: 100 height: 30
    platform(background.x+25, 100);
    platform(background.x+125, 100);
    platform(background.x+225, 130);
    platform(background.x+425, 240);
    platform(background.x+630, 180);
    platform(background.x+850, 125);
    platform(background.x+1050, 360);
    platform(background.x+1250, 265);
    platform(background.x+1490, 205);
    platform(background.x+1770, 130);
    platform(background.x+2050, 240);
    platform(background.x+2420, 340);
    platform(background.x+2790, 450);
    platform(background.x+3050, 360);
    platform(background.x+3300, 265);
    platform(background.x+3555, 190);
    platform(background.x+3810, 100);
    platform(background.x+4170, 250);
    platform(background.x+4570, 430);
    platform(background.x+4810, 330);
    platform(background.x+5150, 330);
    platform(background.x+5490, 330);
    platform(background.x+5750, 240);
    platform(background.x+6010, 145);
    platform(background.x+6480, 550);
    platform(background.x+6940, 330);
    platform(background.x+7200, 230);
    platform(background.x+7450, 130);
    platform(background.x+7810, 130);
    platform(background.x+8220, 330);
    platform(background.x+8650, 595);
    platform(background.x+8890, 485);
    platform(background.x+9240, 485);
    platform(background.x+9570, 485);
    platform(background.x+9850, 390);
    platform(background.x+10120, 290);
    platform(background.x+10350, 180);
    platform(background.x+10790, 450);
    platform(background.x+11050, 360);
    platform(background.x+11300, 265);
    platform(background.x+11555, 190);
    platform(background.x+11810, 100);
    platform(background.x+12170, 250);
    platform(background.x+12570, 430);
    platform(background.x+12810, 330);
    platform(background.x+13150, 330);
    platform(background.x+13490, 330);
    platform(background.x+13750, 240);
    platform(background.x+14010, 145);
    platform(background.x+14480, 550);
    platform(background.x+14700, 440);
    platform(background.x+14940, 330);
    platform(background.x+15200, 230);
    platform(background.x+15450, 130);
    platform(background.x+15810, 130);
    platform(background.x+16220, 330);
    platform(background.x+16650, 595);
    platform(background.x+16890, 485);
    platform(background.x+17240, 485);
    platform(background.x+17570, 485);
    platform(background.x+17850, 390);
    platform(background.x+18120, 290);
    platform(background.x+18350, 180);
  }
  ra = requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
ra = requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

https://jsbin.com/yenure

Comment: Yes, very well. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: I'm glad to here. Please accept this answer so it will help to other people.